# Transfer a task when a person is out of office

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, tasks, issue-tracking

Environment : Foundation 2010

I created a new list with the "Issue Tracking" model.
My workflows include some tasks automatically assigned to a specific person.

But I would like to transfer these tasks, to another person, when these people are out of office.

Obviously if I don't do that, tasks are going to be blocked for some days.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you looking for an automated process?  If so, you would have to probably create a workflow with designer and add a status column to your list which tracks the end-users status.  IF STATUS = PRESENT assign task to Normal Guy, ELSE assign task to That guy.

Comment: An automated process would be great. Thing is in our company our Sharepoint is linked with our ActiveDirectory. Our ActiveDirectory is linked with our Exchange Server. If I understand well the way you gave me, each guy who will be out of office will have to fill in a status field ?

Comment: Yes.  You will need to add a 'Status' column for your personnel.  Then set-up a workflow If Issue equals Issue 1 and Current:Item Status equals Present Send Email to Primary.  Add an Else option, Send Email to back-up.  You can wrap this into one designer workflow.  Add subsequent  "If"  Issue statements with  this conditions Send Email to this person.

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there the only way to do that ? This is not rellaywhat I'm looking for. The best thing will be to find the status of each guy with the Exchange server, see ? Maybe it is too difficult or just impossible ?

Comment: First, I am sorry I mis-read your original post.  There is a way to do it in designer.   It would still work with a status field, If "Person A" equals Out.  You will then add an "Update Item in this list" action to the workflow where you click "this list" and then click "Add".  There you change the "Assigned To" to Person B.  I am not an exchange and can not tell you if you can query exchange for an Out of office reply.

Comment: I think I cannot do that. If each person have to fill in a field at each time she's out office, there will be some troubles. I have to find another way.

Comment: @Slabre finding myself needing a similar solution, were you ever successful in finding one?